# Can't to hide ToolBar with animation when scroll ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-toolbar

I want hide `ToolBar` when I scroll `ListView`. Like [this](https://mzgreen.github.io/images/2/goal.gif):

This my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tabanim_maincontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/actionbar_bg"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this my code in `Activity`:

```
public class ToolBarTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private ListView mListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tool_bar_test);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    final String[] catnames = new String[] { ... // 100 strings
    };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catnames);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this [link](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part3)/) will may help you hide the toolbar as well as FAB

Comment: thanks. I use ListView and make RecycleView - now it's little problem for my project.